# Program that scans begining and ending number of two intervals and compares them

Tags: c, function, intervals

I'm preparing for a programing test at my uni and i'd like to write a program in c which can compare two intervals. I've tried many strategies but nothing seems to quite work properly.I believe there is an issue within my if parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



//functions
int io_menu(int a,int b);
int int_check(int k,int n);
int basic_ui(int k,int n,int i,int j);
unsigned interval(int k,int n,int i,int j);
void printint(char str[]);

int main()
{
    int fir_beg,fir_last,sec_beg,sec_last;

    do{
    basic_ui(fir_beg,fir_last,sec_beg,sec_last);
    }while(int_check(fir_beg,fir_last)==0 || int_check(sec_beg,sec_last)==0);



return 0;
}
//menu for print and scan
int io_menu(int a,int b)
{
    printf("Give Begining number: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    getchar();

    printf("Give Ending number: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    getchar();
}

//integer check
int int_check(int k,int n){

    if(n > 0 && k > 0){return 1;}
    else{return 0;}
}
//main menu
int basic_ui(int k,int n,int i,int j)
{
    char frst[]="first";
    char scnd[]="second";

    printint(frst);
    io_menu(k,n);
    printint(scnd);
    io_menu(i,j);

    if (int_check(k,n)==1 && int_check(i,j)==1)
    {
        printf("Data is correct,please wait\n");
        interval(k,n,i,j);
    }
    else{
            printf("Unable to calculate,please try again later\n\n");
    }
}
//calculation for the intervals
unsigned interval(int k,int n,int i,int j)
{
    if(k!=n && i!=j){
        if(n<i)
        {
            printf("Before");
        }
        else if(k>j)
        {
            printf("After");
        }
        else if(i=k && n>i)
        {
            printf("Meets");
        }
        else if(i=n && k<i)
        {
            printf("Met By");
        }
        else if(k<i && n>i)
        {
            printf("Overlaps");
        }
        else if(k<j && n>j)
        {
            printf("Overlapped by");
        }
        else if(k>i && n<j)
        {
            printf("Strict during");
        }
        else if(k<i && n>j)
        {
            printf("Strict Contains");
        }
        else if(k=i && n<j)
        {
            printf("Start");
        }
        else if(k=i && j>n)
        {
            printf("Started By");
        }
        else if(n=j && i<k)
        {
            printf("Finishes");
        }
        else if(n=j && i>k)
        {
            printf("Finished by");
        }
        else if(n=j && i=k)
        {
            printf("Equal");
        }

    }
    else{printf("Unable to calculate,please try again later\n\n");}
}

void printint (char str[])
{
        printf("Enter for %s interval\n",str);

    return 0;
}
```

To be more specific k,n are the beginning and ending numbers for the first interval as well as i,j are for the second one. Please try to understand that it is my 3d week familiarising  with the c language as well as with programing in general.

Comment: io_menu can not work properly as a,b parameter should be passed by reference not by value. It may not fail but will not return values entered by the user.

Comment: This worked,thanks for your submission,great help!